# Chrome 69 doesn't support Firebase SDK

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, firebase-realtime-database, browser-support

Yesterday everything worked perfectly, this morning I noticed chrome is introducing a new interface, afterwards I checked the chrome version, it is now updated to v69. So far so good.
I then ran my server which is linked to firebase. But I started getting this:

```
09:46:30.598 index.esm.js?76ac:2069 Uncaught FirebaseError {code: "messaging/unsupported-browser", message: "Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's …he firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).", stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't sup….0.0.0:8000/index.js?d00bc69e0c69f561d4af:2672:1)"}code: "messaging/unsupported-browser"message: "Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)."stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).
at Object.factoryMethod [as messaging] (webpack-internal:///311:2077:32)
at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (webpack-internal:///30:134:66)
at FirebaseAppImpl.(anonymous function) [as messaging] (webpack-internal:///30:323:31)
at Object.serviceNamespace [as messaging] (webpack-internal:///30:308:32)
at eval (webpack-internal:///66:51:36)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.js?d00bc69e0c69f561d4af:1240:1)
at __webpack_require__ (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.js?d00bc69e0c69f561d4af:708:30)
at fn (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.js?d00bc69e0c69f561d4af:113:20)
at eval (webpack-internal:///286:55:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.js?d00bc69e0c69f561d4af:2672:1)"__proto__: Error
```

Long error made short: `Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK`

Downgrading to chrome 68 is a solution, but does anyone have a better idea?

**EDIT:**

System information: Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS Linux (64-bit)

Chrome version: 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Node version: v10.9.0

**EDIT:**

The server works just fine while deployed to production, and firefox.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This problem occurs when you are not using HTTPS or `localhost`. This is documented in the official documentations: [source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

> The FCM SDK is supported only in pages served over HTTPS. This is due
> to its use of service workers, which are available only on HTTPS
> sites.

Of course, your problem was caused for using 0.0.0.0 instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 7):

edit: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1220#issuecomment-421317994

**Must be a problem with SSL**

I was testing in Amazon S3 Bucket with no SSL..

For Now the only solution I see is checking the chrome version and disable firebase in 69.

It broke an entire app, Im working on. We using Firebase Cloud Messaging for Push Notifications , and all was well until Chrome 68.

In localhost is working, but at production not.

Updated the scripts :

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-app.js
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-messaging.js

and no success.

funny thing: when i debug chrome

```
if ('Notification' in window) {
  console.log('supported'); } else {
 console.log(' not supported'); }
```

it says push API is supported.

Comment: according to this comment on Sep 27th: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1220#issuecomment-425087339

firebase.messaging implemented in Service Workers require HTTPS. If you need to test locally, I suggest running fire `firebase serve` in your project folder.

Answer (score 5):

**SOLUTION**

I was working on `0.0.0.0:8000`, changed it to `localhost:8000` and it worked, some would argue the huge difference, I would argue the opposite...

Answer (score 0):

try the latest Firebase JS library `Version 5.4.2 - August 30, 2018`.

> Fixed an issue where the `navigator` global was unavailable in some environments.

... while the `NodeJS` version is pretty irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug/spec violation in Firefox. In the current version of Firefox Nightly (version 64), it will also throw this error.

Comment: So it working on firefox is a bug in firefox? I don't think so, it worked perfectly on the previous chrome, such bug would've been caught instantly by a community of chrome and firebase combined size. Don't you agree?