# FCM problems using IP address

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to get notification. If I'm running localhost:8000, it works correctly. But if I change to my local Ip: 192.168.0.144:8080, it doesn't work and shown the error:

"**Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).**"

Please help me thanks so much.

Comment: Try out a https connection, also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199810/chrome-69-doesnt-support-firebase-sdk, are you using chrome 69?

Comment: @Badgy Thanks for your suggesstion, but not working bro.